# Dokuwiki with LDAP error: User authentication is temporarily unavailable

Tags: php, ldap, dokuwiki

I'm trying to setup Dokuwiki with LDAP in my local computer.

---

The Dokuwiki version is 2014-05-05 "Ponder Stibbons"

**Authentication settings**

```
authtype: authldap
```

**Plugin Authldap (bundled plugin) settings**

```
plugin»authldap»server: localhost
plugin»authldap»port: 10389
plugin»authldap»usertree: ou=People,o=sevenSeas
plugin»authldap»grouptree: ou=Groups,o=sevenSeas
plugin»authldap»userfilter:
plugin»authldap»groupfilter:
plugin»authldap»version: 3
plugin»authldap»binddn: uid=admin,ou=system
plugin»authldap»bindpw: secret
```

**Local.php content**

```
<?php
/*
 * Dokuwiki's Main Configuration File - Local Settings
 * Auto-generated by config plugin
 * Run for user: 
 * Date: Fri, 20 Jun 2014 10:04:50 +0200
 */

$conf['title'] = 'Sample Wiki';
$conf['license'] = 'cc-by-sa';
$conf['useacl'] = 1;
$conf['authtype'] = 'authldap';
$conf['superuser'] = '@admin,jhallett';
$conf['disableactions'] = 'register,resendpwd,profile';
$conf['proxy']['user'] = 'admin';
$conf['proxy']['pass'] = '<b>OU9sLi8nXVw=';
$conf['plugin']['authldap']['server'] = 'localhost';
$conf['plugin']['authldap']['port'] = 10389;
$conf['plugin']['authldap']['usertree'] = 'ou=People,o=sevenSeas';
$conf['plugin']['authldap']['grouptree'] = 'ou=Groups,o=sevenSeas';
$conf['plugin']['authldap']['version'] = 3;
$conf['plugin']['authldap']['binddn'] = 'uid=admin,ou=system';
$conf['plugin']['authldap']['bindpw'] = 'secret';
$conf['openregister'] = '0';

// end auto-generated content
```

---

LDAP is using Apache DS 2.0.0 and Apache Directory Studio 2.0.0 running on Java 1.7.0_51.

Both installed successfully. I have followed the default installation from [Getting Started Guide](http://directory.apache.org/studio/users-guide/ldap_browser/gettingstarted_create_connection.html) and added [sample configuration](http://directory.apache.org/apacheds/basic-ug/1.5-sample-configuration.html) and [sample LDIF](http://directory.apache.org/apacheds/basic-ug/resources/apache-ds-tutorial.ldif).

I'm using the default configuration according to the Getting Started Guide:

```
Default Port: 10389
Default Bind DN: uid=admin,ou=system
Default Bind Password: secret
```

---

When I save the dokuwiki configuration, I got the following error:

```
User authentication is temporarily unavailable. 
If this situation persists, please inform your Wiki Admin.
```

What should I do to fix this problem?

Comment: enable the debug option for dokuwiki and the LDAP plugin and see what additional info you get

Comment: I checked the `Basic:allowdebug` option. I only got the following information: `05:55:34 ::1: checkUpdateMessages(): messages.txt up to date` inside `\DokuWikiStick\dokuwiki\data\cache\debug.log`. Do I missed any debug configuration?

Comment: @AndreasGohr: I got debug information by padding &do=debug in the address bar. Since the text is quite big, I cannot attached it in the main post. What keywords should I check?

Comment: No. Enable allowdebug in the DokuWiki config and enable the debug option of the LDAP plugin. Debug info should be printed along with the error message.

Comment: I got "LDAP err: PHP LDAP extension not found. [auth.php:34]". It seems coming from \DokuWikiStick\dokuwiki\lib\plugins\authldap\auth.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your PHP does not have the LDAP extension installed or enabled. It's needed for AD authentication. Your distribution probably has a separate package for it. Eg. php5-ldap or something.

Comment: I was using the included webserver from dokuwiki download page. I replaced the \php using complete one, then update the user filter and group filter, and it works correctly. It's nice to get the answer directly from the creator. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to use Ubuntu 16.04 you can extend you apache instance with:

```
sudo apt install php7.0-ldap
```

and enable the ldap apache module with

```
sudo a2enmod authnz_ldap
```

Good luck!