# Dokuwiki with LDAP (Version3) on a Synology NAS

Tags: php, ldap, dokuwiki

I'm trying to setup Dokuwiki with LDAP (Version3) on a Synology NAS.

> DokuWiki version is Release 2014-09-29b "Hrun"
>
> Synology version is DSM 5.1-5004 Update 2

**Authentication settings**

authtype: authldap

**Plugin Authldap (bundled plugin) settings**

```
$conf['title'] = '.... wiki';
$conf['license'] = '0';
$conf['useacl'] = 1;
$conf['authtype'] = 'authldap';

$conf['superuser'] = '@wiki_admin';

$conf['plugin']['authldap']['server'] = 'ldap://example.com:389';
$conf['plugin']['authldap']['usertree'] = 'cn=users,dc=example,dc=com';
$conf['plugin']['authldap']['grouptree'] = 'cn=groups,dc=example,dc=com';
$conf['plugin']['authldap']['userfilter'] = '(&(uid=%{user})(objectClass=posixAccount))';
$conf['plugin']['authldap']['groupfilter'] = '(&(objectClass=posixGroup)(|(gidNumber=%{gid}) (memberUID=%{user})))';
$conf['plugin']['authldap']['version'] = 3;
$conf['plugin']['authldap']['debug'] = 1;
```

local.php copied to local.protected.php

I'm always getting following error messages

1. LDAP err: PHP LDAP extension not found. [auth.php:34]
2. User authentication is temporarily unavailable. If this situation persists, please inform your Wiki Admin.

althougt according to [[Dokuwiki with LDAP error: User authentication is temporarily unavailable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24322779/dokuwiki-with-ldap-error-user-authentication-is-temporarily-unavailable][1])

the plugin seems to be installed (bundled) and enabled.

I cannot find any authldap.php in the whole wiki directory.
The \php folder as mentioned in the answer to the above link is not in the DokuWiki tree.
I installed it on a second NAS with no DokuWiki project contents with the same results.
What's going wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

**PHP LDAP extension not found** Your PHP installation is missing the needed LDAP extension. That is completely unrelated to DokuWiki.

The LDAP-Extension is often distributed in a different package (eg. php5-ldap) or it might already be installed but needs to be enabled in your php.ini.

This [post](http://forum.synology.com/enu/viewtopic.php?f=180&t=40267) suggests it can simply enabled in your NAS configuration interface.